# Download multiple files from an FTP server containing two separate patterns

Tags: batch-file, ftp

I'm new to batch scripting and am stuck with a problem.
I have a few files in a folder on an FTP server. The file names are as follows.

```
A20160302.0000+0530-0000+0530_EMS-1440.mrf.bz2
A20160302.0000+0530-0030+0530_EMS-NORMAL.mrf.bz2
A20160302.0015+0530-0020+0530_EMS-SHORTPERIOD.mrf.bz2
A20160302.0015+0530-0020+0530_FMA-PERIOD.mrf.bz2
A20160302.0020+0530-0025+0530_EMS-SHORTPERIOD.mrf.bz2
A20160302.0020+0530-0025+0530_FMA-PERIOD.mrf.bz2
A20160302.0030+0530-0100+0530_EMS-NORMAL.mrf.bz2
```

I want to download only those files which contain `20160302` **and** `NORMAL` both in the file name.

I have tried `mget` with both strings like

```
mget *20160302* *NORMAL*
```

This downloads files containing `20160302` **or** `NORMAL`.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
mget *20160302*NORMAL*
```

---

Your syntax `mget *20160302* *NORMAL*` with the space is the same as two separate `mget` commands like:

```
mget *20160302*
mget *NORMAL*
```

Comment: I tried it again and it works.. Thanks a lot for your help